Coturn turnserver Webrtc status: disconnected
I have configured turnserver on ubuntu 22.0.4 installed coturn and stopped local firewall
It was tested sucessfully in trickle but while accessing from the client getting below error
Avatar started
Webrtc audio channel connected
Webrtc status: disconnected

Please help us fix the issue, its been 2months I am strugling to make this work
Stopped ubuntu firewall, for now testing internally no port is blocked
Here is the turnserver config file
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=1443
verbose
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech 
server-name=turnser.mydomain.com
user=turnuser:e0568e12eddeb073f9463b789ea9298e --created user using turnadmin command
userdb=/var/lib/turn/turndb
realm=turnser.mydomain.com
user-quota=0
bps-capacity=0
max-allocate-lifetime=36000
channel-lifetime=600
permission-lifetime=300
cert=/etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.pem
pkey=/etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.key
log-file=/var/log/turnserver/turn.log
allow-loopback-peers
no-multicast-peers
max-allocate-timeout=36000
pidfile="/var/run/turnserver.pid"
proc-user=turnserver
proc-group=turnserver
no-cli


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

djdomi- I am getting below error while the client is acessing turnserver 173: : ERROR: session 000000000000000006: TLS/TCP socket error: Connection reset by peer 10.139.143.67:21055
173: : session 000000000000000006: usage: realm=<my.domain.com>, username=<>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0
173: : session 000000000000000006: peer usage: realm=<my.domain.com>, username=<>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0
173: : session 000000000000000006: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <my.domain.com> origin <>, local 172.26.16.198:3478, remote >
This is a frequesnt issue and even the Avatar syn is slow

always put these information into your question by editing
